# ViewModel not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've found a bunch on stackoverflow regarding arrays and lists not binding but I just have a simple view model with 4 strings and the post isn't giving me the form values:

ViewModel:

```
public class ReferralNetworkSearchCriteria
{
    public string Email = "";
    public string FirstName = "";
    public string LastName = "";
    public string TaxSSN = "";
}
```

ReferralNetworkController:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    ReferralNetworkSearchCriteria criteria = new ReferralNetworkSearchCriteria();
    return View(criteria);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(ReferralNetworkSearchCriteria criteria)

{
    return View(criteria);
}
```

View:

```
@using OurCompany.ViewModels
@model ReferralNetworkSearchCriteria

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Referral Network";
}

<h2>Search Referral Network</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("Search","ReferralNetwork",FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 column">
            <label>Email</label>            
            @Html.TextBox("Email")
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 column">
            <label>
                First Name</label>
            @Html.TextBox("FirstName")
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 column">
            <label>
                Last Name</label>
            @Html.TextBox("LastName")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 column">
            <label>SSN/Tax ID</label>
            @Html.TextBox("TaxSSN")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-2 column">
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "ReferralNetwork", null, new { @class = "button", @style="width:100%"})
        </div>
        <div class="large-2 column">        
            <button style="width:100%">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>    
}
```

*Edit:
I also tried using `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)` for all the text inputs and still no values on the post. Thanks

Comment: `<button type="Submit" >Search</button>` maybe?

Comment: Just tried it, no go :/

Comment: If you put a break point in the Search function (the HttpPost one), do you have values in criteria?

Comment: I was going to do the search coding in the controller, but I can't search without getting the form values. My plan was to add a list<ofmyEFTable> property to the viewmodel and pass it back to the search page where it will display the results when they're > 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of properties, not fields/variables, otherwise the `DataBinder` simply wont't bind. I also recommend using the `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)` when possible.

```
public class ReferralNetworkSearchCriteria
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TaxSSN { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ugh. I feel dumb. Thank you!